# Trying to add my animation to my idle state, but it just keeps saying "None(Motion)"

Tags: animation, unity-game-engine, animator

I have pulled the animation to the Motion tab both by dragging and trough the select motion search function but neither makes the animation stick to my idle state. Can someone give me a pointer to what im doing wrong?

Comment: You are using an animator?

Comment: yeah ive attached the animator to my object and have set all the states for the object but when i try to add the animations to each states it just doenst register and stay labled as "none(motion)" on the motion field.

Comment: anyone? im pulling out my hair here

Answer (score 7):

One reason could be that the animations are marked as legacy.

Select one or many animation, in the inspector next to the lock, right click, then Debug. Untick the Legacy. No need to save or else.

Comment: Why can we even drag legacy animations into the animation controller? There should be a warning message saying that this won't work because the animation is set to legacy.

Answer (score 0):

The animation which you're trying to set is for another model!
You should use an animation that is for the model.
Or if you insist on using that animation select animation from assets and do a "Control + D" to duplicate it and use new one.

Answer (score 0):

Use the Animator, not the animation controller. I made this mistake when I was following a tutorial. This is only relevant if you are animating .anim files within unity itself. Animation controller is the way to go if you import animations for your specific model.